# StructureMap -> Choose a Specific Constructor with Parameters

Tags: c#, constructor, structuremap

I am trying to use structure map to get an instance of StackExchangeRedisCacheClient https://github.com/imperugo/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions/blob/master/src/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core/StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.cs

I have seen other questions that ask about specifying a parameterless constructor instead of a constructor with parameters. However, I want to specify a specific constructor that has parameters.

I can't find any examples of this.

I want to use this constructor:

```
public StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(ISerializer serializer, IRedisCachingConfiguration configuration = null)
```

I want StructureMap to get an instance of ISerializer and give a null for IRedisCachingConfiguration.  How can I do this?

I want to do something similar to this but it doesn't work:

```
For<ISerializer>().Singleton().Use<JilSerializer>().SelectConstructor(() => new JilSerializer());
For<ICacheClient>().Singleton().Use<StackExchangeRedisCacheClient>().SelectConstructor(() => new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(GetInstance<ISerializer>, null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you configure the container with a factory function that returns a null instance of the IRedisCachingConfiguration.  The actual instances do not need to be resolved in the SelectConstructor expression, as this is just used for matching the constructor, hence the nulls.

```
For<ISerializer>().Singleton().Use<JilSerializer>();
For<IRedisCachingConfiguration>().Singleton()
    .Use("null config", () => (IRedisCachingConfiguration)null);
For<ICacheClient>().Singleton()
    .Use<StackExchangeRedisCacheClient>()
    .SelectConstructor(() => new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(
        (ISerializer)null,
        (IRedisCachingConfiguration)null));
```

Or another approach would be to configure a factory function for your ICacheClient and simply invoke the constructor you want, bypassing the need to configure a null `IRedisCachingConfiguration`.

```
For<ICacheClient>().Singleton().Use(c => 
    new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(c.GetInstance<ISerializer>(), null));
```